# Pop up modal only working on first element in table, and wont open again after second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring, twitter-bootstrap

I am having some trouble with the pop up modal I have implemented into my web application. When I click on the second item within my table of 'users' in this circumstance, the modal does not activate, although when I click on the first one it works. Another thing is when I open the modal on the first item and then close it, and then attempt to re-open it does not pop up. Any ideas?
My call to pop up the modal:

```
$("#update_user_button").click(function() {
                    var userId = +$(this).val();
                    $.get('${pageContext.request.contextPath}/ajax/' + userId, function(user) {
                        $("#updateModal #id").val(user.id);
                        $("#updateModal #name").val(user.name);
                        $("#updateModal #username").val(user.username);
                        $("#updateModal #email").val(user.email);
                        $("#updateModal #authority").val(user.authority);
                    });
                    $("#updateModal").modal('toggle');
                    $("#alert").hide();
                    $("#error_name").hide();
                });
```

After I submit the modal form using this function below, I cannot activate the modal again.

```
.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/updateUser",
                    data: $("#updateForm").serialize(),
                    success: function(response) {
                        $("#alert").show();
                        $("#users_table_container").load("${pageContext.request.contextPath}/users #users_table");
                    },
                    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                        alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown); 
                    } 
                });
```

The button to instantiate this ajax:

```
<td>
                    <button data-togle="modal" href="#updateModal" id="update_user_button" class="btn btn-primary" value="${user.id}">Update</button>
                </td>
```

And then the actual modal itself:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="updateModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="Update User Information" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Update User Information</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

                    <div id="alert" class="alert alert-success fade in">
                        Information has been <strong>successfully</strong> updated.
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                    </div>

                <form id="updateForm">
                    <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" /> 
                    Name:
                    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class=""/><div id="error_name" class="error_font">Username and password must be between 3 and 30 characters.</div>
                    <br /> 
                    User name:
                    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" />
                    <br /> 
                    Email:
                    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
                    <br /> 
                    Authority
                    <select name="authority" id="authority">
                        <option value="ROLE_USER">ROLE_USER</option>
                        <option value="ROLE_ADMIN">ROLE_ADMIN</option>
                    </select>
                    <br />
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button id="updateUser" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div><!--/ modal content: end -->
    </div><!--/ modal dialog: end  -->
</div><!--/ modal: end -->
```

Comment: Is the button code described in your table row reused? If so you'd need to give them different IDs.

Comment: Yes, it continually gets repeated. Which doesn't make it unique? and will not work correct? How do i get around this?

Comment: No two elements in the same HTML document should have the same ID. If you want them all to be accessible by the same jQuery script do `class="update_user_button"` instead of `id="update_user_button"` and do `$(".update_user_button")` instead of `$("#update_user_button")`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like the button with id `update_user_button` is repeated in you table, id of a element must be unique in a document.

In this case use a class attribute instead of ID. Also there is no need to use `data-toggle="modal"` since you are using `$("#updateModal").modal('toggle')` in your click handler.

```
<td>
    <button class="btn btn-primary update_user_button" value="${user.id}">Update</button>
</td>
```

and

```
<div class="modal hide fade" id="updateModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="Update User Information" aria-hidden="true">
```

then

```
// Here we are hiding Modal To show Initially
$("#updateModal").modal({
    show: false
});

$(document).on('click', ".update_user_button", function () {
    var userId = +$(this).val();
    $.get('${pageContext.request.contextPath}/ajax/' + userId, function (user) {
        $("#id").val(user.id);
        $("#name").val(user.name);
        $("#username").val(user.username);
        $("#email").val(user.email);
        $("#authority").val(user.authority);
    });
    $("#updateModal").modal('show');
    $("#alert").hide();
    $("#error_name").hide();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/jY5Zv/)

Comment: This works great! Only trouble is now, once I have used the pop-up modal once, it does not activate again? I dont know why

Comment: what do you mean by `it does not activate again`? is it not opening in the second time?

Comment: So I click on the modal button once and it opens, when I close the modal. I try to activate the same button again, and the modal will not show.

Comment: Yes it does not open the second time I click it. Not sure why

Comment: @MatthewBobrowski if you click on another button is it showing?

Comment: I have implemented these changes, and now the modal is actually not even showing.

Comment: @MatthewBobrowski have you added the script in a dom ready handler

Comment: I think I know what the problem will now be. Could it be after I do an ajax post, to save the user's information. I am reloading the table again after success of update.

Comment: Yeah so the modal becomes inactive after I post the data inside the modal.@Arun P Johny

Comment: @MatthewBobrowski yes that is the reason... you need to use event delegation